# C++ autorun in win 8

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder

Is it right to use old techniques for win 8 to autorun my program?

I don't have win 8 to test, so I hope somebody already knows.

when PC was restarted, my program is not started, what can cause this ?

Comment: Consider this...do you want to support older versions of Windows? If it can be used to support older versions and works perfectly on Windows 8 I see no reason to implement two solutions for the same problem when a single existing solution will do.

Comment: i want just the program to be portable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autorun specified using that registry key works the same on Windows 8 as it did in earlier versions of Windows. Feel free to continue using that method.

Comment: I use this method and it is not working on win7 and win8, what can cause that ?

Comment: yes i found my self, unfortunately this question didn't helped me to found the issue, and your answer was accepted because it is true and on subject as you remarked so i removed all my comments which is not related to question]

Comment: So, out of curiosity, what was the problem.

Comment: value name must be exactly same as program name without exe, and i have added "quotes"

Comment: Well, whenever I've done this, I've never had to make value name match program name. And I don't think you always need quotes. Usually the system can work it out. That said, quotes are wise. I suspect that was the issue.